# Stripping down C-like comments from otherwise legal json

Tags: java, json, parsing

Suppose you have a json file which includes C style comments

```
{
  "foo": {
    "default_level": "debug",
    // A comment
    "impl": "xyz"
  },
  "bar": [
    {
      /*This is a comment*/
      "format": "%l%d %c ….",
      "rotation": "daily, 1_000_000",
    }
  ]
}
```

Before this is json is deserialized, using `Java` what would be the easiest way to strip these comments off? Lets assume that only single line `//` and multiline `/**/` comments are supported.

Ultimately, i'd like to read in a `String` representation of the same file but w/o comments:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "default_level": "debug",
    "impl": "xyz"
  },
  "bar": [
    {
      "format": "%l%d %c ….",
      "rotation": "daily, 1_000_000",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You almost have 10k rep, you should know that you should show what you have tried or researched. If you don't want to do the work on your own, I'll take 15$/hour and finish this in one :P

Comment: How is the C example valid json? the separator necessarily has to be a newline.

Comment: Can your json have comment characters as data like "comment":"/* this is data */"??

Comment: This is, of course, not legal JSON.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, it is understood

Comment: @RaviThapliyal only `//` and `/* blah */` allowed

Comment: @jlordo I thought "I could write my own comment parser but obviously don't want to do that" was implicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually a non-trivial problem. I would personally suggest the Comment-Stripper library which IMO does a pretty good job of this. Found here: https://github.com/Slater-Victoroff/CommentStripper?source=cc

More fully functioned and debugged version was forked a while ago, but hopefully that should solve this issue.

Full-disclosure: I wrote this library after asking a similar question and realizing there weren't any great solutions I could find.

Alternately if you just want to remove comments I believe you can do it trivially in Python, which you can just call with Jython.

```
import json
return json.dumps(json.loads("file.json"))
```

If you're dead set on Native Java you can do basically the same thing using GSON instead. (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and I assume it's also possible with Jackson (http://jackson.codehaus.org/) though I would suggest the lighter GSON for something this simple.

GSON example:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
BufferedReader br = //BufferedReader for your source;
String clean = gson.toJson(gson.fromJson(br, Class.class))
```

Example is given with the understanding that there is some supporting code that needs to go with it, this example only encapsulates the use of GSON. The rest should be pretty trivial (Make a generic  type class), check out the GSON docs if you're really having trouble.

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: Can you please provide an example on how this can be done using `gson` please?

Answer (score 1):

Probably better luck processing this as Javascript, since JSON is nearly a subset of Javascript, and JSON + C-like comments would in fact be as nearly a subset of Javascript.  Try:

[Looking to remove comments from a large amount of javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403098/looking-to-remove-comments-from-a-large-amount-of-javascript-files)

Basically - just run it through your favorite minifier first.  Note that [JSON is not a strict subset of Javascript](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset) so you will need to jam your nearly-legal JSON into legal Javascript before you could trust a minifier. Fortunately this is solvable by a simple find-and-replace.

Answer (score -4):

Try this regex.

```
String jsonData =
"{\n"+
"  \"foo\": {\n"+
"    \"default_level\": \"debug\",\n"+
"    // A comment\n"+
"    \"impl\": \"xyz\"\n"+
"  },\n"+
"  \"bar\": [\n"+
"    {\n"+
"      /*This is a comment*/\n"+
"      \"format\": \"%l%d %c ….\",\n"+
"      /* This is a\n"+
"         multi-line comment */\n"+
"      \"rotation\": \"daily, 1_000_000\",\n"+
"    }\n"+
"  ]\n"+
"}";

System.out.println(
       jsonData.replaceAll("//.*\\n\\s*|/\\*.*?\\n?.*?\\*/\\n?\\s*", "")
);
```

***Output:***

```
{
  "foo": {
    "default_level": "debug",
    "impl": "xyz"
  },
  "bar": [
    {
      "format": "%l%d %c ….",
      "rotation": "daily, 1_000_000",
    }
  ]
}
```

*Note:* This won't work if your json could have comment characters as data like

```
 "comment":"/* this is data */", "impl": "abc//xyz"
```

Comment: This will also remove json content like `"impl": "abc//xyz"`

Comment: Now you have two problems.

Comment: @djechlin could you elaborate some more please?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Comment: Regex is not the solution, -1

Comment: @djechlin I think it's kinda unfair to down vote a *working* solution based on difference of *philosophy*.

Comment: Your solution is incorrect. The downvote is because your solution is incorrect. You're going to edit it again, then it's still going to be incorrect. Then you're going to edit it one more time, and it will still be incorrect. Then you'll edit it one more time, at which point it will be correct and inscrutable.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Escaping comments is not trivial, regex is meant for trivial problems.

Comment: @tomdemuyt Yes, I do understand the train of thought going here. It's like validating email or a piece of html. No regex would match almost all of them but people still use them if its *good enough* for their data set. I mean no need to get fancy with the words: "I have two problems". I was just trying to help.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Entirely different from using regex for email in which case there is actually a defined regex that will match every email, it's just long and gross. Regex is fundamentally unable to match 100% of higher order grammars like html or comments because these grammars are not context free. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages for learning exactly what that means.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Yes, I mentioned HTML in my comments and I've seen applications use a much less complicated regex for email. So, although it won't match every email address on this planet it was good-enough for the use-case. And, at the time of posting this solution OP had shared a sample input to filter and had not mentioned that data could contain comments within. I do understand the concerns other have shared in comments but I do not think they warranted a down vote because the solution as such was not wrong or incorrect.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus How ironic is that your *CommentStripper* library makes use of regex only. Just goes to prove that we usually want a solution that works for our *data set* rather than aiming for a fool-proof 100%. I had chosen the same approach but unfortunately, others disliked it.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal You're looking at an out-of-date fork, also it doesn't just use regex, it uses regex on grammatical transformations of the original form which reduce it to a context-free grammar by ensuring that it passes the pumping lemma. That said, it got taken over by someone else a while ago.